# Label not visible on top of TableViewCell in TableView Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am working on a small app to help keep organized for school (schedule, to-do's, map, etc). I am trying to make a TableView for the schedule, where each cell would be designated to a time period of the day (ex. 8:30-10:00). When I drag the label on top of the cells in the TableView, they appear fine in storyboard but the label is not visible in the Simulator. I'm sure its a simple problem but I can't seem to figure it out.

**Here is a shot of the layout I have in the storyboard**

[image]

And what it looks like in the Simulator...

[image]

Comment: Are you using dynamic prototypes or static cells for the table view cells in your table?

Comment: Either the labels aren't hooked up to the cell, or there are no rows in that section.  Also look into using a single dynamic prototype cell, instead of a different cell for each time period.